# Rails 6 local server booting : RAILS_ENV=development environment is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I just created a new Rails 6 app. Everything went fine until I tried to launch the local server with `rails s`, and got this error message :

```
RAILS_ENV=development environment is not defined in config/webpacker.yml, falling back to production environment
Exiting
```

and

```
Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/remy/dev/voter/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/remy/dev/voter/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

But when I run `rails webpacker:install` I still have the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error usually hints at an unmet Yarn dependency. Try installing or updating Yarn before running `rails webpacker:install`.

Here are the [Yarn Docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable) for quick reference just in case.

Comment: Thats worked, I was missing dependencies and `yarn install` did the trick.

Comment: Can you tell me what happens when we run this command? This is not found in rails documentation getting started.

Comment: I had to install node first